# List member equality in FsUnit

Tags: unit-testing, f#, fsunit

I want to check that two lists have the same members, irrespective of order:

```
let memCount items = items |> Seq.countBy id |> Map.ofSeq
let memberEquals items1 items2 = memCount items1 = memCount items2
```

Currently, I use this in a test as follows:

```
memberEquals expected actual |> should be True
```

However, this is not quite as nice for error reporting.

Can I extend FsUnit to add a `memberEquals` similar to `equals` or `contains`? Alternatively, I could just always sort the lists before comparing them. What is the best approach here?

(I am using FsUnit with nUnit, for what it's worth.)

Comment: It's these sorts of non-trivial scenarios where you'll see Unquote really begin to shine, simply because F# itself so excels at expressing these types of assertions. See https://gist.github.com/2919920.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `memberEquals` function doesn't test if the lists have the same members (only the same number of items). The easiest way to do that is:

```
let memberEquals items1 items2 = (set items1 = set items2)
```

If the lists may contain duplicates you'll need to sort and compare them as lists instead.

<sup>†</sup> You can read about the `set` function on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353747).